# Print permutation tree python3

Tags: python-3.x, permutation

I have list of numbers and I need to create tree and print all permutations, e.g. for `[1, 2, 3]` it should print 
 
`123 
 132 
 213 
 231 
 312 
 321`

 Currently my code prints first element only once: 
`123
 32
 213
 31
 312
 21`

 How do I fix it?

```
    class Node(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = None
        self.data = None
        self.depth = None


class PermutationTree(object):
    def __init__(self, numbers):
        numbers = list(set(numbers))
        numbers.sort()
        self.depth = len(numbers)
        self.tree = self.generate_root(numbers)
        self.create_tree(numbers, self.tree.children,  1)

    def generate_root(self, numbers):
        root = Node()
        root.children = []
        root.depth = 0
        for i in numbers:
            tree = Node()
            tree.data = i
            tree.depth = 1
            root.children.append(tree)
        return root

    def create_tree(self, numbers, children, depth):
        depth += 1
        if depth == self.depth + 1:
            return
        for child in children:
            reduced_numbers = list(numbers)
            reduced_numbers.remove(child.data)
            child.children = []
            for j in reduced_numbers:
                tree = Node()
                tree.data = j
                tree.depth = depth
                child.children.append(tree)
            self.create_tree(reduced_numbers, child.children, depth)

    def print_tree(self):
        self.print(self.tree)

    def print(self, node):
        for i in node.children:
            print(i.data, end="")
            if not i.depth == self.depth:
                self.print(i)
                print("")

test = [1, 2, 3]
permutation_tree = PermutationTree(test)
permutation_tree.print_tree()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty good example showing why [side effects](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40297/what-is-a-side-effect) should be done in as few places as possible.

## Side effects everywhere

Your approach is like this: "*I will print one digit every time it is needed.*" This approach gives you limited control over side effects. Your code prints many times in different recursion depths and it's hard to keep track of what is going on.

## Side effects in as few places as possible

Another approach to this problem is creating side effects in one place. "*I will generate all permutations first and then print them.*" Such a code is easier to debug and can give you better control of what is going on in your code.

If you write your code like this:

```
def print_tree(self): # this function takes care about printing
    for path in self.generate_path(self.tree):
        print(path)



def generate_perm(self, node): #this function takes care about generating permutations
    if not node.children: 
        return [str(node.data)]
    app_str = str(node.data) if node.data else ""
    res= []
    for child in node.children:
        for semi_path in self.generate_perm(child):
            res.append (app_str + semi_path)
    return res
```

P.S.
generate_perm can be rewritten to be more efficient with [yields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do).